# Trying to pass session variables from ASP to ASP.NET

Tags: authentication, session-management, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

We are doing a slow rollout of pages. basically the Login page is in ASP.NET and the old pages are in ASP Classic which are placed in an Iframe below the menu. They have two different servers that process the menu/pages. What is the best way to pass the users session from .NET to ASP Classic.

I had thought maybe it would be possible to modify the .NET login to send the user credentials to ASP page at the same time when they post their login. Is there any issues with this or is there a cleaner way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Your ASP.NET code can read all the cookies in the domain, including the classic ASP session cookie, even though it doesn't use it.  You can take advantage of that.

1. Handle signon on the ASP.NET side.  The framework should create both an ASP and an ASP.NET session for you, passively, in addition to whatever other cookies are created by your authentication process.
2. Write ASP.NET code that reads the classic ASP session cookie and creates a `JointSession` record in the database indicating which user is currently signed on.  Store both the ASP session cookie value and the current ASP.NET session ID (each in their own column), along with the user ID, roles, and whatever else needs to be shared between the two sites.
3. Write ASP code that reads its own session cookie and looks up any corresponding `JointSession` database record.  If one is found, the ASP side of the site can infer that a user has signed on to ASP.NET, and can create its own matching session, initializing it from the fields in the `JointSession` record.
4. If you need to pass data between ASP and ASP.NET, add columns to `JointSession`, or perhaps use EAV schema.  If it were me, I'd just add a VarChar column and throw some JSON in there.